# Passing filepaths containing spaces with xargs

Tags: bash, filepath, xargs

I'm trying to use xargs to pass the contents of a variable containing zero or more filepaths separated by newlines to another command and have been having inconsistent success.

My input is the output of this:

```
newHTK=`grep -Fxv -f $TMPFILE /Users/foo/.htk`
```

Which generates the aforementioned list of filenames. Here's where things go wrong (or sometimes inexplicably right):

```
echo "$newHTK" | xargs -L 1 xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment htk
```

The intention is for is to use each line in `$newHTK` as a filename argument for `xattr`. What usually happens is `xattr` splits the input at the spaces. I think I might need to escape the filenames coming out of the `echo` command or somehow enclose them in double quotation marks (Any advice on an easy way to do this would be appreciated). But if that's the case why did it work for some of the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `xargs` `-I` flag (if you have it I don't know what its portability is) to do this.

```
grep -Fxv -f $TMPFILE /Users/foo/.htk | xargs -I % xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment htk %
```